# nginx always gives 500 error for JS file after I change it

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, web-server

I'm running nginx on a local CentOS 6.3 server. I have a particular javascript file that loads in a webpage. If I change the javascript file, and refresh the webpage, I always get a 500 error. Then when I refresh it again, the JS file loads just fine.

Later, if I change the JS file again, and refresh the browser, same 500 error. Refresh a second time and again, it loads just fine. It only gives the 500 error on the first refresh.

Why is this? Here is my server config:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name www.mysite.local;

        rewrite ^(.*) http://mysite.local$1 permanent;
}

server {

        listen          80;
        server_name     mysite.local;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/mysite.local/access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/mysite.local/error.log;
        rewrite_log     on;

        root            /vhosts/mysite/mysite.local/public;
        index           index.php;

        # Heres my redirect, try normal URI and then our Laravel urls.

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        include         /etc/nginx/templates/other;
```

Here is the include file:

```
if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}
```

Error Log:

```
2014/09/06 23:19:58 [crit] 27884#0: *29935 open() "/vhosts/mysite.local/public/js/testfile.js" failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable), client: 192.168.1.51, server: mysite.local, request: "GET /js/testfile.js HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.local", referrer: "http://mysite.local/some/page"
```

I am the only person connecting to the server. No other traffic. And it doesn't matter if I refresh the page immediately after saving the file or if I wait (like 15 seconds or something). It's always a 500 error the first refresh.

I am accessing/editing the files over a Samba connection.

Comment: Any line from nginx error log?

Comment: Good call. Updated the question with the log error.

Comment: Some troubleshooting step I propose. (1) Can you access the file (for example: run `cat jsfile`) after file was saving and before accessed by nginx? (2) Did you use sharing file system (samba/nfs/etc)?

Comment: I can access the file just fine while SSH'ing into the server. I am editing the file over samba from a Windows PC. I have the file opened on my editor on the Windows PC, over Samba. I edit and save it here. I can `cat` the file just fine.

Comment: Maybe related to this issue: [Handling the 'open() 11 resource temporarily unavailable' error with Nginx](http://rafaelsteil.com/handling-the-open-11-resource-temporarily-unavailable-error-with-nginx/)

Comment: That certainly sounds like the issue. However I have tried multiple text editors including Notepad and the issue persists. Wonder if this is a Samba config issue or nginx config issue.

Comment: Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202567/nginx-resource-temporarily-unavailable-using-a-samba-share

Comment: Good job. Can you post the answer from stackoverflow to the answer section and accept it? It'll be useful to future reader because [comment has less visibility than answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931) and this question won't floating in un-answered pool

Comment: Done. Also it's more of a SF question than an SO question anyways, so this is a better place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with Samba, not nginx. I solved the problem by adding the following to my Samba configuration:

```
oplocks = no
level2 oplocks = no
```

Originally found in the following SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202567/nginx-resource-temporarily-unavailable-using-a-samba-share

Comment: it would be great if you accept your own answer. So the future readers know that this solution is working (at least) for you :)